# How to make thread communication using deque?

Tags: java, multithreading, deque

I writing a program, in which One thread is for inserting elements in to `Deque`, another is for reading elements from same `Deque`. For that I am doing like this,

```
public class ThreadCommunicationInDeque {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Deque deque=new LinkedList<>();
    InsertingThread it=new InsertingThread(deque);
    ReadingThread1 rt=new ReadingThread1(deque);
    it.start();
    rt.start();
}
}

class InsertingThread extends Thread{

Deque deque=new LinkedList<>();
InsertingThread(Deque deque){
    this.deque=deque;
}

@Override
public void run(){
   for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
       try {
           deque.add(i);
           System.out.println(deque.getLast());
           Thread.sleep(100);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(InsertingThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
}

}
class ReadingThread1 extends Thread{

Deque deque=new LinkedList<>();

ReadingThread1(Deque deque){
  this.deque=deque;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    if(deque.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No elements in queue");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println(deque.getLast());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadingThread1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
}
```

My problem is Here `InsertingThread` is working fine but `ReadingThread` is stops by displaying No `elements in queue`. I am not getting where I am doing wrong , Can anyone tell me how to fix it. And tell me is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have consumer running in a loop like a thread should be. It just runs for once and see's that there are no elements in queue (which might be true if say consumer was the thread that ran first) and then exits safely from the thread.

To begin with try something in your consumer's run method like and then fine tune it if you need:

```
while (true) {
        if (deque.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No elements in queue");
        } else {
            System.out.println("consumed " + deque.removeLast());//note get will still have queue populated so remove seems better?
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
}
```

By the way, you are unnecessary creating instance of dequeue in your producer and consumer. You could just remove the instantiation i.e. from

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

To

```
Deque<Integer> deque;
```

if you just want to display last element from within a thread (You could just do it from main method though), then you could do it by calling join method as below (so it lets producer complete and then start consumer thread) in your main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    InsertingThread it = new InsertingThread(deque);
    ReadingThread1 rt = new ReadingThread1(deque);
    it.start();
    it.join();
    rt.start();
}
```

Comment: Oh thank u . . . My exact requirement is to display the last inserted element in queue . .

Comment: @Raghu: Then I don't see the use of two threads. It will unnecessarily complicate the code. You'll have to add a boolean variable to check if  producer has finished and only then you'll be able to get the actual last element from consumer when it runs.

Comment: Thank u very much, small doubt , I dont want to exeute `ReadingThread` in infinity loop, I want a condition to stop it , How can I do that, I did with `i<deque.size()` but didnt work

Comment: That's follow up question. If you think this answer's what you needed then accept it, so it can be closed and raise a new one

Answer (score 1):

Order in which `threads` are executed is random and cannot be determined. So starting producer thread `it.start()` does not mean insertions will always be before you retrieval `rt. start()`. Since you will be inserting. For retrieving you should try replacing code with one given by almas.